# Changing pngs in apktool

Tags: android, eclipse

I have decompiled an apk using apktools on my mac and would like to know if it is possible to change the png icon and splash screen on apktools and if so how because there is no guidance that i can find on the net

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change an image file in an APK, apktools is not needed.
Just replace the png file with a zip utility and resign the app with jarsigner (available with a Java Development Kit or the Android SDK).

Comment: Could you explain how to do this? im a newbie to all of these programs, and the links i found are not helpful

Comment: Since I do not use a Mac, I have no idea which zip utilities are easy to use, but most GUI zip utilities have a file browser like interface that allows you to drag and drop the files to/from it.